# How to get request body in Node.js HTTP2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http2

I have the following code, but no idea how to get the body from the request:

```
var http2 = require('http2');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http2.createSecureServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('localhost-privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('localhost-cert.pem')
})

server.on('error', function (error) { console.error(error) })

server.on('stream', function (stream, headers, body) {

  var method = headers[':method']
  var path = headers[':path']
  var body = body || ''

  console.log(method, path, body)

  stream.respond({
    'content-type': `text/${type}`,
    ':status': 200
  })

  fs.readFile(file, function (error, file) {
    if (error) file = fs.readFileSync('error.html')
    return stream.end(file)
  })
})

server.listen(3443)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should consider the `stream` as a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams)

```js
server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
    var chunks = [];

    stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    stream.on('end', function () {
        // Here is your body
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);

        // Not sure if useful
        chunks = [];    
    });

});
```

Also, according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_event_stream) the third argument of `server.on('stream'` callback is `flags`, not `body`.